# Process elements of Set<Foo> and create Set<Bar> using streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Set<String>` of `"hostname:port"` pairs and from that I'd like to create a `Set<InetSocketAddress>`. I tried it like:

```
Set<InetSocketAddress> ISAAddresses = StrAddresses
    .stream().map(addr -> new InetSocketAddress(
        addr.split(":")[0],
        Integer.parseInt(addr.split(":")[1])));
```

But this produces the following error in *IntelliJ*:

> Incompatible types. Required `Set<InetSocketAddress>` but 'map' was
>   inferred to `Stream<R>`: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so
>   that `Stream<R>` conforms to `Set<InetSocketAddress>`

Something must be wrong with how I'm using the map and the lambda.

Comment: What does "**doesn't work" mean? Does it not compile? Does it output a wrong result? Please clarify exactly what is happening.

Comment: As a note, please stick to **naming conventions**. variable names should always start with a lower-case letter (same for method names and camel-case only for classes).

Comment: @tom You should probably put that in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: In addition to adding the `collect` call I'd advise using two `map` calls to avoid splitting twice. `.map(addr -> addr.split(":")).map(arr -> new InetSocketAddress(arr[0], Integer.parseInt(arr[1))`

Comment: @PaulBoddington Good point, saves the second `split` call. Added that in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Stream#map` function does **not return** a `Map`. It **transforms** (maps) the current elements of your stream to other elements. So it generates from a `Stream<X>` a `Stream<Y>` using the **given** *transformation function* which takes `X` and outputs `Y`.

```
StrAddresses.stream()                           // String
    .map(addr -> new InetSocketAddress(
        addr.split(":")[0],
        Integer.parseInt(addr.split(":")[1]))); // InetSocketAddress
```

You start with a `Stream<String>` and end up with a `Stream<InetSocketAddress>`.

To quote from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream **consisting of the results** of **applying** the **given function** to the elements of this stream.

---

If you want to transform that stream into a `Set` you need to use the `Stream#collect` method like so:

```
StrAddresses.stream()
    .map(addr -> new InetSocketAddress(
        addr.split(":")[0],
        Integer.parseInt(addr.split(":")[1])))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The utility method `Collectors.toSet()` returns a collector for a well optimized `Set`. If you for example explicitly want a `HashSet` you can use this instead:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-):

> Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream. A mutable reduction is one in which the reduced value is a **mutable result container**, such as an `ArrayList` [...]

---

As a small note, you currently split the same element twice each time:

```
addr.split(":")[0],                     // First
Integer.parseInt(addr.split(":")[1])))  // Second
```

You could save that additional `split` procedure by memorizing the value before. In this case this can be done elegantly by using a second `Stream#map` call. First we transform from `Stream<String>` to `Stream<String[]>` and then to `Stream<InetSocketAddress>`:

```
StrAddresses.stream()                                 // String
    .map(addr -> addr.split(":"))                     // String[]
    .map(addrData -> new InetSocketAddress(
        addrData[0], Integer.parseInt(addrData[1])))  // InetSocketAddress
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that `Stream#map` is a **lazy operation**. This means that Java will not *transform* the whole `Stream` from `A` to `B` once you call the method. It will wait until a *non-lazy* (finalizing) operation like `Stream#collect` comes, then traverse the `Stream` and apply each *lazy operation* **element-wise**. So you can add as many `Stream#map` calls as you like without producing *extra loops* over the whole `Stream`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **[`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)** the `Stream` of `InetSocketAddress` addresses returned after mapping to `Set`. This can be done as -

```
Set<InetSocketAddress> ISAAddresses = StrAddresses.stream()
                  .map(addr -> new InetSocketAddress(addr.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(addr.split(":")[1])))
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```